# Why my new class object already got fulfilled field?

Tags: python, class, init, mutable

I run this code:

```
class My_class:
    def __init__(self, Field = []):
        self.Field = Field

    def set_Field(self, Field):
        self.Field = Field

    def add_to_Field(self, number):
        self.Field.append(number)

    def get_Field(self):
        return self.Field

Object_1 = My_class()
Object_1.Field.append(1)
print(Object_1.get_Field())

Object_2 = My_class()
print(Object_2.get_Field())

Object_1.set_Field([2])
print(Object_1.get_Field())

Object_3 = My_class()
print(Object_2.get_Field())
```

In output I get:

```
[1] 
[1] # Why there is [1]?
[2]
[1]
```

I understand first print, but why with second and fourth I get [1]? When I create `Object_2` with no input `Field = []`from `__init__` should work but it looks like it's not. Why `append(1)` changes fields of all future classes while `set_Field([2])`doesn't. Is that connected with mutable nature of lists?

Comment: Something like this: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: Ok, thx for that guys. That's what i looked for.